# Spotify fetching artist information - Error 503 Service

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, spotify

Spotify has a WEB API and it allows for you to query their database. I am trying to fetch the following link for example:
`http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json?q=Nas`. Is this a server side issue or a problem on my side? 
Okay so I am having a really weird error all of a sudden it says:

```
Error 503 Service Unavailable

Service Unavailable

Guru Meditation:

XID: 333508029

Varnish cache server
```

It worked fine a couple of hours ago and now all of a sudden it just won't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service seems to be down. I'm seeing the same thing. If you check out the responses listed on [this page](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/#introduction) it says a 503 error means the service is temporarily unavailable. Which is exactly what the error message itself says, but it's nice to have confirmation. Wish I knew how long it might be down though.